# How to wait for balanceOf before I execute a transfer?

Tags: web3js, javascript

Ok, I'm new into JS and web3 and MetaMask. I'm still lost about Promise and async/await after reading them for 5 times!

I want to call my smart contract balanceOf method to check if there's enough balance of token before I execute a transfer.

How do I actually wait for this balanceOf value to return to my JS script then only I proceed?

You know, getting the balanceOf takes like only 1 sec, but I know sometimes the user's finger is faster than the brain.

I tried async/await function below but my main code doesn't "wait", it just continues on. I'm using web3 1.0.

Then, I execute the transfer in a separate function. What I'm doing now is firstly I set the token balance using setTokenBalance(balance). Then check if I have enough balance by calling getTokenBalance(). If yes, then I do the transfer. Which works but it's kinda funny cos there's a split second that getTokenBalance shows '0' since it hasn't got the correct balance data.

```
var tokenBalance = 0;
async function retrieveTokenBalance(contract, walletAddress) {

      await contract.methods.balanceOf(walletAddress).call(function(err,res){
            if(!err){
                console.log(res);
                setTokenBalance(res);
            } else {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });

}

function setTokenBalance(balance) {
    tokenBalance = balance;
}

function getTokenBalance() {
    return tokenBalance;
}
```

Comment: BTW, you should tag your question under `web3.js` rather than `web3j`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your retrieveTokenBalance is an async function, try this...

```
retrieveTokenBalance(smartContract, walletAddress).then(function(result){

    //If sufficient token
        //Do your token transfer
    //Else
        //Do something else like alerting the user

});
```

You can learn more about async/await in Javascript here - https://tutorialzine.com/2017/07/javascript-async-await-explained which explains a lot better than other sites.

Comment: Awesome! It worked. And thanks for the tutorial tip.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const balance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(walletAddress).call();
await setTokenBalance(balance);
```

From your description, it sounds like function `setTokenBalance` executes a transfer, which means it has to be an `async` function, hence the `await` for its completion.

Comment: The setTokenBalance is just a function to set a variable in JS that stores the token balance. It doesn't do any calls to MetaMask

Comment: @warnerque: So the question in the title makes no sense - "before I execute a transfer" - where exactly in your code are you attempting to execute a transfer???

Comment: I execute the transfer in a separate function. The idea is first I set the token balance using setTokenBalance(balance). Then check if I have enough balance by calling getTokenBalance(). If yes, then I do the transfer.